# Flex: Hiding a tab in TabNavigator

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-mobile, flash-builder4.5

I have set the tab ViewNavigator atrributes `visible="false"` and `includeInLayout="false"`.
But the tab still appears.

Here's my code:

```
<s:navigators>
    <s:ViewNavigator id="loginTab" label="Login" firstView="views.LoginView" width="100%" height="100%" visible="false" includeInLayout="false"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="VIDEOS" firstView="views.VideosView" width="100%" height="100%" icon="@Embed('assets/thumbs/video.png')"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="EBOOKS" firstView="views.EbooksView" width="100%" height="100%" icon="@Embed('assets/thumbs/ebook.png')"/>
</s:navigators>
```

What am I doing wrong?
p.s. I am using Flash Builder 4.5 developing an Android mobile app.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem using `this.tabbedNavigator.removeItemAt(0);`